# Is it posible to create an array of int names variable

Tags: java, arrays, int

I would like to know if it is posible to build an array of int names variable. Sample below and i would like them initialized to 0;

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk;
```

Comment: yes, what have you tried which didn't work?

Comment: I tried my example but i'm not sure if it is correct way to create the array and i can't initilize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer to my question of an array of int variables. I tried the code below and it seems to work.

```
int h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk;
int counter[] = {h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk};

\\ display the value of int, int that's in array;
tvpwlikectr.setText("" + counter[0]);
```

Comment: could you check the question you asked Marvin?

Comment: (Is it posible to create an ARRAY of int NAMES variable). The initialization is just something that i added. I'm new to programming, my terminology is a little bit off.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if it is correct way to create the array and I can't initialise it.

Try

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk;
h1i1ctrlk = new int[length]; // an array of length full of 0s.
....
h1i5ctrlk = new int[length]; // an array of length full of 0s.
```

to set all elements of an array with a value `1.0`

```
Arrays.fill(hii1ctrlk, 1.0);
```

If you have specific values in mind you can use

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk = { 0, 1, 2, 10 };
```

or

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk;
hii1ctrlk = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 10 };
```

or use a loop

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk = new int[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    h1i1ctrlk[i] = i * i;
```

You can also use a `Map<String, int[]>` like this

```
Map<String, int[]> ctrlk = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(int h = 1; h <= 9; h++) {
   for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       String key = "h"+h+"i"+i;
       ctrlk.put(key, new int[length]);
   }
}
```

Comment: probably not what OP wants, he needs sth like `Map<String, Int>`, to have keys and int values

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Thx! But how about initializing them with different value other than 0?

Comment: @MarvinD I have added an example using Array.fill()

Comment: I was looking for int variables in array. I have a for loop that process images. I want to assign an int for each images per for loop. So if i have an array of int variables, it will be part of the for loop. When a image is seleced the int associated to it will be incremented.

Comment: You can use the example I gave to work out how to do that. Let us know if you have a problem doing that.

Comment: I think i found my answer "see anwser" but i wasn't sure if what i found can be done with the map example you have. thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just like this:

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk = {1, 2, 3};
```

or

```
int[] h1i1ctrlk = new int[3]; //array length of 3
```

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I need an array of int variables  not an int array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try  this will do some work for you
try to print all  arrays one by one, it will we initialized with 0 
and all arrays length will be 1

```
      public class IntName{


        public static void main(String args[])
            {
               int[] h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk = {0};
               h1i1ctrlk = h1i2ctrlk = h1i3ctrlk = h1i4ctrlk = h1i5ctrlk;
               System.out.println(h1i1ctrlk.length);
            }



}
```

Comment: I get syntax error with this code int[] h1i1ctrlk, h1i2ctrlk, h1i3ctrlk, h1i4ctrlk, h1i5ctrlk = {0};

Comment: you mean this single line is enough achieve that ? ofcourse not because only final one will be initialized with {0} array run and check the result of code you. given

Comment: Could you tell me the error you got ? I run this exaclty work !

Comment: for you I have edited the answer with whole class check that.

Comment: I tried it again and it does works but i think i found the answer that i'm looking for. See my answer. thx for the effort.